# Database timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timezone

I want to set different timezone for different database on a single cpanel(Phpmyadmin).I don't know how to set different timezone for different database.
Please help me .. it is possible or not,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not possible to change the timezone of a single databse on an instance, but as Madan has pointed below, you can control this for a `session` You can also refer to discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916747/set-mysql-database-timezone-to-gmt

Comment: Are you looking to have different timezone for different database on same server or different server ?

Comment: Hi Manish..I am looking for different timezone for different database on same server.

Comment: @samsad is your question solved?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP / MYSQL. Place the following code at top of the page or index page.

`date_default_timezone_set('timezone_name');` example `America/New_York`

Only MySQL (works only for current session)

`mysql> SET time_zone = 'timezone_name';`

For global change

`mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'timezone_name';`

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Madan... I am talking about database(MYSQL)...I don't want to set timezone through the PHP Code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments and answer above that you cannot change the time settings per database on the same MYSQL server.

In addition to the answer from Madan Sapkota, I would like to add the following.

At the start of a query with time/ date values you start with SET TIME_ZONE = ""; And then continue with your normal query.

Another way to query your database is to use the convert_tz() function.

```
CONVERT_TZ(column_name,'+00:00','-05:00')
CONVERT_TZ(column_name,'UTC','America/New_York')
```

The first number / name is the current time zone the second is the desired time zone. To check which timezone your database is using use `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` in your command line.

Further reading: [How does one deal with multiple TimeZones in applications that store dates and times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207976/how-does-one-deal-with-multiple-timezones-in-applications-that-store-dates-and-t), [How to correctly set mysql timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434030/how-to-correctly-set-mysql-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when capturing the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I solved it the following way:

In your database class have a class with the this query `SET @@session.time_zone = '+02:00';`, in your construct(make sure you put you timezone). This will have to execute everytime you query the database.

I hope this helps.